How to check if an apt installed package was already installed from before?
I was following a tutorial to setup intel's quick sync for a program. However, I think I followed the wrong tutorial. During the setup I used apt install to install 2 packages, I can't remember what they were exactly right now but I think they were

sudo apt install intel-media-va-driver-non-free i965-va-driver

I have them recorded at home, so I will find exactly the package when I go back. When I did this, it asked to update the kernel from 5.15.0-119 to 5.15.0-121.
I would like to undo any changes I did, or at least undo the apt installs, I think the kernel update isn't an issue. My question and what I'm confused about is how do I check if the packages I installed were already on my system. If they were and I just updated them, then I'll keep them. However, if they weren't there from before, I would like to apt remove them. How do I know if I installed them from scratch or just updated them and they were already in the system before what I did?
Is there something I should look for in the logs, if yes, how?
Start-Date: 2024-09-13  06:08:25
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: python3-pkg-resources:amd64 (59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.1, 59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.2), python3-setuptools:amd64 (59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.1, 59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.2)
End-Date: 2024-09-13  06:08:26

Start-Date: 2024-09-14  06:08:03
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-121-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-121.131, automatic), linux-headers-5.15.0-121:amd64 (5.15.0-121.131, automatic), linux-headers-5.15.0-121-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-121.131, automat>
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (5.15.0.119.119, 5.15.0.121.121), linux-generic:amd64 (5.15.0.119.119, 5.15.0.121.121), linux-image-generic:amd64 (5.15.0.119.119, 5.15.0.121.121)
End-Date: 2024-09-14  06:08:48

Start-Date: 2024-09-14  06:09:02
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-headers-5.15.0-117-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-117.127)
End-Date: 2024-09-14  06:09:03

Start-Date: 2024-09-14  06:09:16
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-117-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-117.127)
End-Date: 2024-09-14  06:09:18

Start-Date: 2024-09-14  06:09:31
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-headers-5.15.0-117:amd64 (5.15.0-117.127)
End-Date: 2024-09-14  06:09:33

Start-Date: 2024-09-14  06:09:46
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-modules-5.15.0-117-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-117.127), linux-image-5.15.0-117-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-117.127)
End-Date: 2024-09-14  06:09:50

Start-Date: 2024-09-15  18:23:34
Commandline: apt install i965-va-driver-shaders intel-media-va-driver
Requested-By: karim (1000)
Install: libpciaccess0:amd64 (0.16-3, automatic), i965-va-driver-shaders:amd64 (2.4.1-1), libigdgmm12:amd64 (22.1.2+ds1-1, automatic), libva2:amd64 (2.14.0-1, automatic), libdrm-intel1:amd64 (2.4.113-2~ubun>
End-Date: 2024-09-15  18:23:35

I can see that it installed a lot of packages when I installed the drivers. But it doesn't explicitly say if it updated anything. Does that mean I can just remove these packages and I'll be good?
Also, for the kernel. I didn't manually trigger it and it seems like it updated a few days before. Was it just a coincidence that I got that purple screen about rebooting to update?

You can explore the apt logs; ie. /var/log/apt/history.log  ....  myself I use view /var/log/apt/history.log and then search that using standard POSIX terminal searching...  but there are many ways of seeking details...

@guiverc I think that view is some flavor of vi and therefore really not a very good suggestion unless we know the OP is a vi user. If you don't use vi, it is really not a very helpful tool since even exiting the thing requires you to know obscure commands (:q). Krusion, try less /var/log/apt/history.log or nano /var/log/apt/history.log instead.

@terdon yh definitely prefer nano over vi. I'll check it out when I go back home. Will it say that it updates/overrides or something similar?

@terdon I've updated my question with the logs I had found and asked more specific questions.

You'll see in the older entries of the log that when it's upgrading an already installed package, the line is like: Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (5.15.0.119.119, 5.15.0.121.121), .... But for your apt install i965-va-driver-shaders intel-media-va-driver command, there is no such line, so no packages were upgraded. Only these were newly installed: Install: libpciaccess0:amd64 (0.16-3, automatic), i965-va-driver-shaders:amd64 (2.4.1-1), libigdgmm12:amd64 (22.1.2+ds1-1, automatic), libva2:amd64 (2.14.0-1, automatic), libdrm-intel1:amd64 (2.4.113-2~ubun>

Perfect thanks! So I should apt remove i965-va-driver-shaders intel-media-va-driver and double check that the other packages were also removed and I'll be good. Just out of curiousity, why did the kernel update by itself and if it did, was it just a coincidence that it had asked me to reboot for it to take effect when I apt installed the other packages?
